# Matlab diff command with bigger step

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

The command `diff` calculates differences between two consecutive elements. Is there any way to calculates differences between two nonconsecutive elements?

For example, with

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

is there any command to find

```
[x(3)-x(1),x(4)-x(2),x(5)-x(3),x(6)-x(4)] = [2,2,2,2]
```

or

```
[x(4)-x(1),x(5)-x(2),x(6)-x(3)] = [3,3,3]
```

And in general, for the case of a matrix? I can write some code for this; I just wonder if there any existing command in Matlab for this?

An example of the matrix case

```
x = [1,2,3,4;1,3,5,7;2,4,6,8]
```

and we want to find

```
[x(1,3)-x(1,1),x(1,4)-x(1,2);x(2,3)-x(2,1),x(2,4)-x(2,2);x(3,3)-x(3,1),x(3,4)-x(3,2)] = [2,2;4,4;4,4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For vectors

I would use convolution with kernel `[1 0 ··· 0 -1]`, where the number of zeros depends on the **desired step**. This can be done with function [`conv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; % data
s = 2; % step
result = conv(x, [1 zeros(1,s-1) -1], 'valid');
```

gives

```
result =
     2     2     2     2
```

### For matrices or N-dimensional arrays

The above can be generalized using [`convn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html), with a kernel defined as before but oriented along the **desired dimension**:

```
x = [1,2,3,4; 1,3,5,7; 2,4,6,8]; % data
s = 2; % step
d = 2; % dimension
result = convn(x, reshape(([1 zeros(1,s-1) -1]), [ones(1,d-1) s+1 1]), 'valid');
```

gives

```
result =
     2     2
     4     4
     4     4
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but will convolution work for matrix in general?

Comment: Great solution for N-dimensional arrays!

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks! [_Convolution is the key to success_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650/36398) :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of such a function, but you can simply set up a very simple anonymous function

```
stepDiff = @(x, s) x(:, s:end)-x(:, 1:end-s+1);
```

Will give outputs like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

>> stepDiff(x, 2)
ans =
   1   1   1   1   1      

>> stepDiff(x, 4)
ans =
   3   3   3

x = [1, 2, 3, 4; 1, 3, 5, 7; 2, 4, 6, 8];

>> stepDiff(x, 3)
ans =
   2   2
   4   4
   4   4
```